# Removing contiguous spaces in a String without trim() and replaceAll()

Tags: java, string

I have to remove leading and trailing spaces from the given string as well as combine the contiguous spaces. For example,

```
String str = "    this is    a   string  containing numerous  whitespaces   ";
```

and I need to return it as:

```
"this is a string containing numerous whitespaces";
```

But the problem is I can't use `String#trim()`. (This is a homework and I'm not allowed to use such methods.) I'm currently trying it by accessing each character one-by-one but quite unsuccessful.

I need an optimized code for this. Could anybody help? I need it to be done by today :(

Comment: is this homework? are there restrictions for your solution (i.e. do you have to use a loop versus regular expression etc) ?

Comment: yes. It is a homework and I'm restricted to use such methods

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: "Such methods" is way too vague. What *are* you allowed to use? What have you tried? The fact that you need it done by today is irrelevant to the question...

Comment: I'm allowed to use `charAt()`, `toLowerCase()`, `length()` and `substring()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not permitted to use these methods. I've to do this with loops
>   and all.

So i wrote for you some little snipet of code if you can't use faster and more efficient way:

```
String str = "    this is    a   string  containing numerous  whitespaces   ";
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
String correctedString = "";
boolean space = false;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == ' ') {
        if (!space && i > 0) {
            buff.append(c);
        }
        space = true;
    }
    else {
        buff.append(c);
        space = false;
    }
}
String temp = buff.toString();
if (temp.charAt(temp.length() - 1) == ' ') {
    correctedString = temp.substring(0, buff.toString().length() - 1);
    System.out.println(correctedString);
}
System.out.println(buff.toString())
```

### Note:

But this is "harcoded" and only for "learning".

More efficient way is for sure use approaches pointed out by @JonSkeet and @BrunoReis

Comment: thanks for your reply. It helped me out well. Yeah I know that those are the good approaches, but I'm restricted to use them

Comment: there is a minor problem, if i do have trailing spaces then it still add a space at the end. I'd tried but unable to resolve the issue

Comment: @MohammadFaisal add to the comment this string what you mean. i will try to fix it.

Comment: for the string `"    this is    a   string  containing numerous  whitespaces   "` the output is: `this is a string containing numerous whitespaces `. (with an extra space at the end if there are trailing spaces). I'll be very thankful of you if you please fix this.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal reason was that you cannot know whether string will have last two spaces, or three etc. but with algorithm mentioned above always you will have one extra space at the end(algorithm ensures only one space between words). So you can remove it simply. check updated answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27692/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-sajmon)

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Answer posted before we were told we couldn't use `replaceAll`. I'm leaving it here on the grounds that it may well be useful to other readers, even if it's not useful to the OP.

> I need an optimized code for this.

Do you *really* need it to be opimtized? Have you identified this as a bottleneck?

This should do it:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

That's a regular expression to say "replace any contintiguous whitespace with a single space". It may not be the fastest possible, but I'd benchmark it before trying anything else.

Note that this will replace *all* whitespace with spaces - so if you have tabs or other whitespace characters, they will be replaced with spaces too.

Comment: coz it is a homework I'm not permitted to use these methods. I've to do this with loops and all.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: And you didn't think to mention this in the question? Please be more careful in future - when you fail to mention vital pieces of information, you waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

What about `str = str.replaceAll(" +", " ").trim();`?

If you don't want to use `trim()` (and I really don't see a reason not to), replace it with:

```
str = str.replaceAll(" +", " ").replaceAll("^ ", "").replaceAll(" $", "");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove White Spaces without Using any inbuilt library Function
this is just a simple example with fixed array size.

```
public class RemWhite{ 
public static void main(String args[]){ 
String s1=" world qwer ";
int count=0;
char q[]=new char[9];
char ch[]=s1.toCharArray();
System.out.println(ch); 

    for(int i=0;i<=ch.length-1;i++)
   {
     int j=ch[i];
     if(j==32)
     {
      continue;
     }
   else
      q[count]=ch[i];
      count++;

      } 
   System.out.println(q); 

  }}
```

Comment: Have you even tried running the example. I think not!. The print statement will print object reference of the array `q` and not its contents.

Answer (score 0):

To remove single or re-occurrence of space.

```
public class RemoveSpace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char space = ' ';
        int ascii = (int) space;

        String str = "    this is    a   string  containing numerous  whitespaces   ";
        char c[] = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i++) {
            if (c[i] == ascii) {
                continue;
            } else {
                System.out.print(c[i]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any inbuilt methods here's what you refer

```
private static String trim(String s)
{
    String s1="";boolean nonspace=false;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)!=' ' || nonspace)
        {
            s1 = s1+s.charAt(i);
            nonspace = true;
        }
    }
    nonspace = false;
    s="";
    for(int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(s1.charAt(i)!=' ' || nonspace)
        {
            s = s1.charAt(i)+s;
            nonspace = true;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package removespace;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemoveSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the string");

        String str= scan.nextLine();

        String str2=" ";

        char []arr=str.toCharArray();

        int i=0;

        while(i<=arr.length-1)
        {
            if(arr[i]==' ')
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                str2= str2+arr[i];
                i++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(str2);

    }
}
```

Comment: some explanation needs to be added buddy.

Comment: Did you have initialized `str2` with a whitespace `" "`?

Answer (score -1):

This code is used for removing the white spaces and re-occurrence of alphabets in the given string,without using trim(). We accept a string from user. We separate it in characters by using charAt() then we compare each character with null(' '). If null is found we skip it and display that character in the else part. For skipping the null we  increment the index i by 1.
try this code to get the solution of your problem.

```
String name = " abc "; 
System.out.println(name);
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
    char ch = name.charAt(i);
    if (ch == ' ') {
        i = 2 + i - 2;
    } else {
        System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation so that OP can understand why your solution works